# Adding number of observations to seaborn catplot/stirpplot

Tags: statistics, seaborn

Pretty straightforward. I want to see how many datapoints there are in a certain category.
e.g:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.stripplot(x='day', y='size', data=tips)
```

I get:
[graph without n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWa9Q.png)

what I want is:
[graph with n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x4A7.png)
(it's done with paint, so not exactly like that, but you get the point

Comment: Is this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55157558/11306028

Answer (score 1):

```py
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

x_col = 'day'
y_col = 'tip'
ax = sns.stripplot(x=x_col, y=y_col, data=tips)
nobs = tips.groupby(x_col)[y_col].count()
for i,n in enumerate(nobs):
    ax.annotate(f'n={n}', xy=(i,0), xycoords=('data','axes fraction'), ha='center')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't keep track of the order of the labels (in the dataset that I'm actually using), so I did something a bit different:

`xlabels = [x.get_text() for x in ax.get_xticklabels()]
nobs = t.groupby('tag')['match_iou'].count()
for i,l in enumerate(xlabels):
    n = nobs[l]
    ax.annotate('n={}'.format(n), xy=(i,0), xycoords=('data','axes fraction'), ha='center')
`